# Refrencing android project with another android prject

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to reference with another android project, I am generating jar of one project and included that within another project but there is an error as Error generating final archive: found duplicate file for APK: res/values/strings.xml

How it can be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert one project to a [library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) and [reference it](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) from the other project.

Comment: thanx for suggestion Jason but when I include this as library project there is an error in pom.xml where desired package not found(when i want to build with Maven).

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this with Maven. But it seems [it is possible](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use an android library project. 
Go to the projects preferences and check "Is library project".
On the main project, simple add the library project you just created.
That should resolve this.

[Library Project in the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject)